# How to retrieve value from Firebase to RadioGroup

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i want to take the value from the Firebase and set the text into RadioButtons who placed inside the RadioGroup.

MY XML :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupEdit"
    android:layout_width="131dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editNama"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textKelamin">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonLakiHapus"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Laki Laki"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonPerempuan"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Perempuan"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

MY Kotlin Code :

```
 var query = reference.orderByChild("nik").equalTo(nik)
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        nama.setText(userSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString())
                        tanggal.setText(userSnapshot.child("tanggal_lahir").getValue().toString())
                        tempat.setText(userSnapshot.child("tempat_lahir").getValue().toString())
                        // How to setText into Radiogroup
```

The examples of my Radio Button :
[image]

how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chose the correct RadioButton from the data (String) you receive from your Firebase db. then you can do something like this

```
if(userSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString() == "Laki Laki") {
    radioButtonLakiHapus.isChecked = true
} else if(userSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString() == "Perempuan") {
    radioButtonPerempuan.isChecked= true
}
```